# Android: How to use string resource from xml file in property of customized preference?

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

I've implemented a custom seekbar preference, using this site - [seekbar preference](http://robobunny.com/wp/?p=190) and it works just fine. Now I want to add values to the seekbar's customized properties from the `string.xml` file instead of hard-coding them:
Instead of writing `customseekbar:unitsRight="Seconds"` I want to have a string resource like `<string name="units">Seconds</string>` and use it like this: `customseekbar:unitsRight="@string/units"`. I've tried to implement this [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html). My relevant code is:
**attrs.xml**

```
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="CustomSeekBarPreference">
    <attr name="unitsRight" format="reference|string"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

And the constructor -
**CustomSeekBarPreference.java**

```
public class CustomSeekBarPreference extends Preference implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private static final String APPLICATIONNS="http://CustomSeekBarPreference.com";
    public CustomSeekBarPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs, R.styleable.CustomSeekBarPreference, 0 ,0);
        mUnitsRight = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomSeekBarPreference_unitsRight);
        a.recycle();
}
```

and the **layout** -

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:customseekbar="http://CustomSeekBarPreference.com" >

<com.x.sharedpreferencestestapp.CustomSeekBarPreference
    android:key="1"
    android:defaultValue="30"
    android:max="100"
    customseekbar:min="0"
    android:title="Default step"
    customseekbar:unitsRight="@string/units"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

But as you can see, I get 'null' instead of the right value: [image: screenshot]
Even if I change the value to a fixed string instead of string resource, like `customseekbar:unitsRight="Seconds"` I still get the same result. And just to make it clear - if I stick to the original code of the seekbar preference: `mUnitsRight = getAttributeStringValue(attrs, APPLICATIONNS, "unitsRight", "defaultValue")` it works, but not with string resource.

Comment: You've got the wrong namespace in the layout. Change it to `xmlns:customseekbar="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`.

Comment: @MikeM. If I change the name space I get an error - since I have other custom attributes, like `min`, I get - `No resource identifier found for attribute 'min' in package 'com.x.sharedpreferencestestapp'`. Does it mean that I have to add a third namespace (and so - how?) or that I must implement values at the `attrs.xml` for **all** the customed properties?

Comment: Nah, you don't need to define a third one. You'll just need to add your custom attributes to your `<declare-styleable>`. That example is rather odd, in that it's kinda handling the XML attributes "raw". The reason `getAttributeStringValue()` works is because it's specifying its own namespace in retrieving the attributes' values. When you use `obtainStyledAttributes()`, it's using a particular namespace that is basically `"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/" + packageName` (`res-auto` is a shortcut), so it won't pull any attributes with your `"http://CustomSeekBarPreference.com"` namespace.

Comment: Alternatively, I suppose you could modify the `getAttributeStringValue()` method to handle string resource references, too, and keep the current setup, but I'd have to do a little research to be sure how that's done, exactly.

Comment: @MikeM. Ok, that makes sense. Can you please add your first 2 comments to an answer?

Comment: Will do. I don't have time right now to put together a proper answer, but I'll get one posted when I get a chance later, unless someone else beats me to it. Please do leave a comment if you have any issues in implementing this. Cheers!

Comment: @MikeM. I've added all the custom attributes to the `attrs.xml` and it works just fine, but now I have an issue with the `max` attribute - the program ignores the value I put in the xml - `android:max="50"` has no effect, even that it was not customized by me. If I make it a custom attribute - it works. On the other hand - other attributes like `android:title` works just fine. What is the difference between `android:max` and `android:title` and how can I make my program use the `max` value?

Comment: `Preference` doesn't know anything about the `max` attribute. It's only looking for [a certain set of attributes](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/preference/Preference.java#70), so anything that it doesn't handle is ignored, unless you do it yourself. The reason it works in the original example is because [they're explicitly using the Android resource namespace to pull that value straight from the "raw" attributes](https://github.com/scottyab/dimsum/blob/master/src/com/robobunny/SeekBarPreference.java#L56), and set it on the `SeekBar`.

Comment: You could use that system attribute, if you wanted to, instead of defining your own, but you'd still have to handle reading and setting that value yourself. To do that, you would use `<attr name="android:max" />`, then it would be included in the `R.styleable.CustomSeekBarPreference` array, and `obtainStyledAttributes()` would know you want its value in the returned `TypedArray`.

Comment: Btw, I feel I kinda misspoke earlier. You could certainly define a third namespace to take care of just that one string reference attribute, but I figured it's more straightforward and less unwieldy to just make everything a custom attribute, instead of doing part of it one way, part another. Sorry if I misled you.

Comment: @MikeM. You did not mislead me. I understood my mistake and was able to fix it. I moved the `max` attribute to my own namespace, I'll have to decide if to leave it there or to use a third namespace, but you helped me a lot, so thank you! And I still suggest that you'll answer this question, so I can accept it.

Comment: Sorry that took so long. I got caught up in an urgent project yesterday. Anyhoo, I looked into handling reference values, and included an example of that in the answer. It ended up being pretty easy, and so might be preferable. Please lemme know of any errors, if you happen to give it a try. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting null for that attribute value because of the namespace you've declared for it in the layout XML - `http://CustomSeekBarPreference.com`.

As far as I'm aware, the `obtainStyledAttributes()` method can only pull attributes that are in the standard Android resource namespace – `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android` – or your app's resource namespace, which is `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/` plus the app's package name. Attributes in any other namespace will be ignored, and will not be in the returned `TypedArray`, which is why you get null no matter if the value is a hardcoded string, or a resource reference.

In the example you're following, they've used a similar non-standard namespace, but they're pulling the value directly from the `AttributeSet`, specifying that namespace in the `getAttributeValue()` call thereon. I can't say that I've seen this particular method often used in this manner, and the only benefit I can see to it is that it saves you from having to define your own custom attributes, which is a rather trivial task.

There are a couple of ways to fix this.

---

- Move those layout attributes into your app's namespace, and define an `attr` resource for each.

  This is the method demonstrated in the developer page you've linked, and is probably the most common and familiar way to implement custom `View` attributes.

  First change the namespace declaration in the layout to:

  ```
  xmlns:customseekbar="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto‌​"
  ```

  <sup>(The `res-auto` segment is a convenience that will cause the actual namespace name to be appropriately constructed with the current package name, as previously described.)</sup>

  With your posted setup, this will then cause an error with `customseekbar:min`, since you've not defined `min` as an attribute resource (`attr`) in your app. You can simply define that `attr`, and then handle it the same way you're handling `unitsRight`; i.e., retrieve its value from the `TypedArray` returned from `obtainStyledAttributes()`. You would do the same for any additional custom attributes you might need.

---

- Modify the `getAttributeStringValue()` method in the `CustomSeekBarPreference` example to handle resource references as well.

  This may be the simpler option, as far as modifying the given example, but directly accessing the `AttributeSet` values prevents those values from being adjusted for any theme or style that you might wish to apply. If that's not a concern, then the necessary changes are rather simple.

  In the modified method, we just need to first check if the attribute value is a resource value, using `AttributeSet#getAttributeResourceValue()`. If that method returns a valid identifier, we retrieve the actual value with `Resources#getString()`. If not, we treat the attribute value as a plain string.

  ```
  private String getAttributeStringValue(AttributeSet attrs, String namespace,
                                         String name, String defaultValue) {

      String value = null;
      int resId = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(namespace, name, 0);

      if (resId == 0) {
          value = attrs.getAttributeValue(namespace, name);
          if (value == null)
              value = defaultValue;
      }
      else {
          value = getContext().getResources().getString(resId);
      }

      return value;
  }
  ```

  Using this method, you would not need to define your custom attributes, and the layout namespace can remain as you have it in the posted snippet.

Comment: I've used the first method that you've suggested and it's working fine. Thank you for the detailed answer!